# jQuery JSON nested loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
function drawDimensions(divid) {
    $.getJSON('dimensions.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            var ppp = $('#' + divid).append("<div class='dTitle'><img src='images/cleardot.gif' />" + index + "</div><br>");
          $.each(this, function(k, v) {
              $('<div>').append(v).appendTo(ppp);
          });
        });
    });
}
drawDimensions('dim');
```

I'm trying to nest the divs so the values from the first loop will be the parents of the divs on the second loop.

What am I doing wrong? the second loop divs are not nested within the first one but simply appended after the first ones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ppp` is actually a reference to `$('#' + divid)`, not to the newly created (outer) `div`.

Try this:

```
var ppp = $("<div class='dTitle'><img src='images/cleardot.gif' />" + index + "</div><br>");
ppp.appendTo('#' + divid);
```

Answer (score 2):

The one obvious mistake (may not be the only) is that `ppp`will still refer to the parent div, not the one you created there.

use `appendTo()` as you do in inner loop, or have the assignment separate, like:

```
function drawDimensions(divid) {
    var $container = $('#' + divid);
    $.getJSON('dimensions.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index) {
          var ppp = $("<div class='dTitle'><img src='images/cleardot.gif' />" + index + "</div><br>");
          $container.append(ppp); // or ppp.appendTo($container);
          $.each(this, function(k, v) {
              $('<div>').append(v).appendTo(ppp);
          });
        });
    });
}
drawDimensions('dim');
```

Try and see how it goes, and tell me in comments.

**Notes about sample code:**

- I cached getting the container div jQuery object, since there is only one anyway
- Also, used $ as prefix to the variable I used. Just common practice with jQuery objects, not required.